# How To Include Classes From Another Namespace In Assembly Instead of Writing Them Into A Separate DLL File?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have a `C#` project with two namespaces. A GUI (`Stoff3GUI` as namespace) with the GUI `xaml` and `.cs` files, marked as starting object and a Library (`Stoff3Lib` as namespace) with all the classes doing the actual work.

Now, when I compile my code, I will receive a `.exe` file `Stoff3GUI.exe` and a `.dll` `Stoff3Lib.dll`. In Visual Studio, both namespaces are part of the same Project.

How can I compile the classes from the `Stoff3Lib` into the `.exe` file without producing a separated `.dll` file?

**Edit:**

Changed the `xxx` to my project name Stoff3 for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both namespaces are part of the same project, you should already only end up getting a single assembly.

This can differ with web project setups (various different flavours of web projects create assemblies in times and manners I've never understood) but for standalone executable projects, it really is "one project produces one assembly" in all cases as far as I'm aware. Double-check that you really only have one project - for example, you shouldn't have any *references* in the project to an `xxxLib` assembly.

Comment: This was what I was thinking. Thus can I take the seperate dll as proof I do not have a single c# project (even tho I have a single Visual Studio project)?

Comment: @ArnoSaxena: It suggests that *something* is not as it seems. Could you post a screenshot of your solution explorer? Are you aware of the difference between a *solution* and a *project*? If you look on disk, how many csproj files have you got?

Comment: I got two (obviously one to much) csproj files. I've got a main folder with two sub folders (Stoff3GUI and Stoff3Lib) both have their own csproj file. With one sln file in the main folder. Thus I believe I can conclude I have two projects and one Solution. What I thought being the "Project" has been in fact the "Solution". Now my question is how can I put the classes from the Lib Project into the GUI Project without moving their physical location (if one can talk about a physical location at all :) )

Comment: @ArnoSaxena: Hmm. Personally I would start a new solution and a new project, and do it "properly" from scratch. It's likely to be cleaner than trying to maintain the existing structure. You can still maintain the directory structure difference, but the location of the project file etc would be asymmetric otherwise.

Comment: But a new Solution would "only" produce a new Folder right next to my Stoff3GUI folder with basically the same files in it. And I still would have to copy all the files from Stoff3Lib to the new folder (or Visual Studio is doing it when I add the files). But I would like to keep the current file path as they are. Isn't there any possibility to add files to a solution without changing their path, thus without copying them to the current solution location?

Comment: @ArnoSaxena: Yes, you *could* use "Add Existing File" to include the existing files. But in the long term I think you'll find it a bit confusing. Going from scratch (just the once!) is going to be a short-term hit for long-term consistency.

Comment: I have missed the option "add as link" in the adding window. Before I had added the files by Drag&Drop. Now I have to add them one by one to choose "add as link" every time :( But I think this will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are doing here.  It sounds like you might have a single 'Solution' with two projects  My immediate thought is just to move the classes you want into the the GUI start project and delete the other project.

Comment: I have a Project folder (Stoff3) with two namespaces (Stoff3Lib and Stoff3GUI). I had the impression the Project is Stoff3 and the two namespaces are part of the Project... Obviously this is a misinterpretation of the Visual Studio set-up, or is it? In the Project-Folder-Explorer they both have their own Icon with the c# icon and a "Properties" subfolder.

Comment: "In the Project-Folder-Explorer they both have their own Icon with the c# icon and a "Properties" subfolder".  This would indicate two separate projects.  I believe you have a single solution (.sln file) and 2 projects (.csproj files).

Comment: Right at the moment it's a bit of a problem to get a screenshot published here. But you are correct. I've got one main folder with files Stoff3.sln and Stoff3.vsmdi. Then I have two folders in this main folder Stoff3Lib and StoffeGUI. Both have their own csproj file (Stoff3GUI/Stoff3GUI.csproj and Stoff3Lib/Stoff3Lib.csproj). So the question is how can I get the one project (Stoff3GUI) to use the other files without loosing the folder hierarchy? If I "just" move the classes in the Project-Explorer, the files will be copied also and that I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you really have is 1 Visual Studio solution with 2 projects.

Since a picture is worth 1000 words, and just to clear up terminology, here's what that looks like in VS2012:

[image: TwoProjects]

The output of this solution is exactly what you describe:

- TwoProjects\Stoff3GUI\bin\Debug\Stoff3GUI.exe
- TwoProjects\Stoff3Lib\bin\Debug\Stoff3Lib.dll

[image]

The easiest way to accomplish what you want is to have a single VS project that contains 2 different namespaces. It's good practice to add folders that match your intended namespace structure, in your case Stoff3GUI and Stoff3Lib:

[image]

When you compile this solution, the output will be a single EXE, but you still maintain the separation of model and view namespaces very clearly in your folder/file structure:

- OneProject\bin\Debug\OneProject.exe

[image]

Comment: analysis of the situation is exact, what you have described above is my situation and the current folder structure of the results. Also I definitely will produce every future project as you have described in your solution. For now in the current project I have added all the class files as file links to the GUI project and so received a single file solution.

Comment: Cool! That said, I personally prefer to split class libraries and executables into their own VS projects (as shown above in the solution with 2 projects). But even then, I use folders liberally so the folder structure matches the namespace structure.